# How do I alternate between different marker colors on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a scatter graph using **matplotlib** in Python. Suppose I want each marker on the graph to be a different colour, so it alternates between a set of colours *(e.g., the points go red, green, blue, red, green, blue, etc.)*, how can that be done? Looking at the documentation I'm guessing it has something to do with `set_markerfacecoloralt(`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest might be to use a scatter plot:

```
x = range(20)
y = 2*np.array(x)
pylab.scatter(x, y, color='rgb')
```

[image]

I think what @tcaswell is suggesting as an alternative in his comment is using `plot` three times with different colors on the appropriate slices:

```
pylab.plot(x[::3], y[::3], 'ro')
pylab.plot(x[1::3], y[1::3], 'go')
pylab.plot(x[2::3], y[2::3], 'bo')
```

Comment: Or use 3 `Line2D` objects.  For performance reasons, `Line2D` instances must be all the same color.